# Select column values not existing in string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sql-server, string

I'm writing a code in **Asp.net c#** to select some values from **SQL Server** database.
I want to get all the values in a table that does not contain the items of a **string array**.

In detail, I have a table named Notifications which contains 2 columns, 'Text' and 'Date'. I also have a string array.

I want to get all the Texts and dates that do not exist in my string array

Thank U all

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: What are you using to connect to your SQL server? SqlConnection and passing a query? Entity Framework? In any case, you could either pass your list of values in the query (something along the lines of `WHERE [Text] NOT IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')`) or you could get all rows and then filter out the ones with a matching value in your code. Which is "better" depends on **many** factors.

Comment: This is the method:
public string GetNotifications(string[] texts)
    {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Text, Date From Notifications WHERE @text != Text", con);

                ...
            }
        }
i need to get all the values not just one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first need to convert your array of strings into a comma-separated list that can be passed into your query. Then have your query filter our any records where the value of the Text column is in that list:

```
public string GetNotifications(string[] texts)
{
    // Create a single string with all values from the texts array.
    // Ex: 'value1','value2','value3'
    // There are many ways to do this; here's one way using string.Join and LINQ:
    var textsAsSingleString = string.Join(",", texts
        .Select(x => "'" + x.Replace("'", "''") + "'")
        .ToArray());

    // Create your query with a WHERE clause that checks against your list
    var query = "SELECT Text, Date " + 
                "FROM Notifications " + 
                "WHERE Text NOT IN (" + textsAsSingleString + ")";

    // Execute the query
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    ...
}
```

Now, this should work fine with a few values in the `texts` array, but if that array gets very large (how large depends on many environmental factors), the performance could start to degrade. However, unless you tell me otherwise, I'll assume the list isn't very long.

**Edit:** If any string in `texts` contains a single quote, this will fail. You need to replace any *single* single quote with *two* single quotes. I've updated the sample above to do this by calling `Replace("'", "''")` on each string in `texts` before adding it to the comma-separated list/string.

Comment: tnx for your quick and helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what way you are connecting to DB but you can always use this:

If using Linq:

```
string sParms = String.Join(",", saParams.Select(str => "'" + str + "'").ToArray());
```

and then you can use `sParms` in your where clause.

If not using Linq:

```
            string[] saParams = new string[3] { "String1", "String2", "String3" };
            StringBuilder sbParams = new StringBuilder();
            foreach(string sStr in saParams)
            {
                if (sbParams.Length > 0)
                    sbParams.Append(",");
                sbParams.Append("'" + sStr + "'");
            }
```

and then you can use `sbParams.ToString()` in your where clause.

Comment: thanks man. you helped me :)